# Auto-completion of round bracket in Auctex

Tags: auctex, balanced-parentheses

When using Auctex to type tex files, **round bracket `(` can't auto-complete** for me. But `[` and `{` can do. How can I fix it?

According to [introduction of LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html), this variable is set to `t`. But the problem also appears. Meanwhile, my auctex can't auto-complete `\(`, `\[`, `\{`, `\left(`, `\bigl[`, `\Bigl\{`.

Emacs is new and interesting for me. Please help me solve it. Thanks!

BTW: Is there any way to delete `(), [], {}` by pairs?

Comment: I can recommand [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens). It has LaTeX support and there is pairwise deletion of brackets via `sp-unwrap-sexp`.

Comment: Dear Timm, `smartparens` works for auto-completion of `(`. But I can't delete `()` by pairs. My key `<backspace>` is bound to `delete-backward-char` and `sp-autodelete-pair` is `t`. How can I modify it to enable the automatic deletion of `()` by pairs? Thanks!

Comment: Is `smartparens-mode` enabled?

Comment: Thanks! It seems no. At the beginning, I use `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)` and it fails. Then I modify it to `(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)` and it works. I'm confused of `LaTex-mode` and `Tex-mode` since `reftex` is enabled by `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)`.

Answer (score 1):

If pressing open the curly or square bracket key completes with the closing bracket, you most probably have electric-pair-mode enabled . It is a built-in minor mode. You can see modes that are active in a buffer by pressing `C-h m`. This mode also removes the closing bracket when there are no internal characters left and you remove the opening bracket.

If the open curly and square brackets work as expected, but the open round bracket do not, you might have some other function bound to it. Check it by pressing `C-h k (`. By default, it runs function `self-insert-command`. If it runs something else, find out what mode has done the binding and disable it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right. The key is bound to `cdlatex`. After I turn off it, the auto-completion works in auctex.

Comment: Great. If you at some  point need to have cdlatex turned on, you can also rebind the '(' globally or for the given major mode to to override the cdlatex binding.